# radio buttons with multiple condition not working-no AJAX

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, please read carefully. Apparently, I'm not a html or javascript man. I'm a PHP guy btw. I suck at html and javscript.and please don't suggest AJAX.  Hi, I have radio buttons, one is called cowboybtn with values("cowboy", "not cowboy") which always constantly appears on the page and the other one is called cigarbtn with values ("cigar", "no cigar"). cigarbtn only appears when I select colours from a dropdown menu. When I click on cowboy button, the cowboybtn will not give effect on the the cigarbtn.It will remain appear since I already
selected colours from the drodpdownmenu.

However, When I change to "others" from the dropdown menu the cigarbtn suppose to dissapear. However it does dissapear. But it shows again, when I click the cowboy button. I tried to hide the cigarbtn by coding something using div and display none, it works, but unfortunately, it will not reappear as usual if I select colours (which was my previous selection).

How do I put an if condition or anything to make it work so that, when I am under the "colours" mode (after selecting colours from dropdown), when I click on cowboy, the cigarbtn remain appears without any effect. And when I change to "others" mode (after selecting others from dropdown), when I click on cowboy the cigar button suppose to dissapears. It's something like multiple conditions on the same button.

To make things easier to understand, if I select fish from dropdowmenu A, I already have radio button B and button C only appears after I selected fish. When I click on button B,nothing affects button C (which is fine). Now when I change to dog from dropdownmenu A, button B remain appears as usual while button C dissapears (which is fine ). Then problem here is, when I click on button B, button C reappears. Hope you get it. I can't post whole script, coz it's too complex. Any help will do. Thanks in advance.

html for cowboybtn

```
<input type="radio" name="optionsalerent" value="cowboy"
id="optionsalerent_0" onChange="ProductSelectionsale(this)" >
cowboy
```

html for cigarbtns

```
<tr>
           <td><div id="condition_2" style="display: none;">category</div>

           <td><div id="condition_0" style="display: none;">
           <input type="radio" name="condition"  value="cigar" id="condition_0">
           cigar</div>
            <div id="condition_1" style="display: none;">   
           <input type="radio" name="condition"  value="no cigar" id="condition_1">
           no cigar</div></td></tr>
      <br>
```

javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function ProductSelectionmain(element) {
            var selectedValue = element.value
                ProductSelectionsale(element,selectedValue);
                if(selectedValue == "colours") {
                             document.getElementById("condition_0").style.display = "inline";
                     document.getElementById("condition_1").style.display = "inline";
                      document.getElementById("condition_2").style.display = "inline";
```

javascript

```
   function ProductSelectionsale(element,selectedValue) {
                var selectedValue2 = element.value

               if(selectedValue2 == "cowboy" && selectedValue == "Others"){
            document.getElementById("condition_0").style.display = "none";
                 document.getElementById("condition_1").style.display = "none";
                  document.getElementById("condition_2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("condition_directowner").style.display = "none";
                        }
else 
{
        if(selectedValue2 == "cowboy"){
            document.getElementById("condition_0").style.display = "inline";
                 document.getElementById("condition_1").style.display = "inline";
                  document.getElementById("condition_2").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("condition_directowner").style.display = "inline";


}}}
```

the value "others" below is from function ProductSelectionmain(element)

```
if(selectedValue2 == "cowboy" && selectedValue == "Others")
```

I'm not 100% sure if im doing it correctly, but the logic is there it think

Comment: `condition_1` and `condition_0` are duplicated. Browser don't know what element he needs to show or hide, **ids must be unique**.

Comment: Hi tqs @Marcos Pérez Gude. sorry for asking, isn't it unique already? since the first one has a digit "1" and the other ends with a digit "0'?

Comment: No. You have an `<input id="condition_1">` and a `<div id="condition_1">`. That's the duplicity.

Comment: ooh.. ok.. noted..tqs @Marcos Pérez Gude. I will have a look and correct that straight away..BUt im still not sure if it works, because I'm trying to figure out a way how to compare the  if state with variable from outside a function..if u look at the above. it only has one variable in the ProductSelectionsale function ..

Comment: The code you are sharing is incomplete and it's impossible to make it work without change everything. With that code, the only that I've seen is the duplicated IDs. But I will study better your code to see if I clarify myself what is the problem.

Comment: noted @Marcos Pérez Gude. I can't show the entire code because it's extremely long and complex, very complex. Btw, give me some time to study out your suggestions, tqs btw.I will get back later.

Comment: You don't have to share all your code. You only need to provide a working example, a Complete, Minimal and Verifiable example. Read the rules of stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It means that you can modify all your code and share only the problem you'll have. Not necessary the complete code. I stay in here waiting for a solution or a different snippet from you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Every element on page must have a unique id attribute(if it has it of cause), even if that elements are different. In your situation you've got

```
<td>
   <div id="condition_0" style="display: none;">
      <input type="radio" name="condition"  value="cigar" id="condition_0">
    cigar
   </div>
```

where `<div>` and `<input>` elements has the same id

Comment: tqs @Littlemyx. I need to test it first, but Im not sure if it works, coz my instinct tells me that i need to grab the variables from outside the function which is in another function and put it in the if statement...something like 
               if(selectedValue == "cowboy" && selectedValue="others"){// the rest will not be displayed} else { //displayed}..maybe.. btw tqs.. let me check first.